# Не видна стрелка back

Tags: android, firebase, android-manifest

Добавил в проект Firebase Invites. Всё работает исправно, но при переходе в активити, нет стрелки назад.
Решил откорректировать прописав в AndroidManifest'e следующее:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activities.DeepLinkActivity"
        android:label="title_map_details"
        android:parentActivityName=".activities.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.vm.sai.activities.MainActivity"/>
</activity>
```

В других активностях такой приём работает, но не тут, скорей всего из элементов отображаемых в самой активности,а именно лого пользователя.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как можно сдвинуть содержимое вправо, чтобы отображалась стрелка-назад.

Полный код deep_link_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/invite_dialog_title"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_headline_material" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_forum_white" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/deep_link_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/deep_link_default"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/invitation_id_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/invitation_id_default"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle_text_size" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:text="@android:string/ok" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Попробуйте переопределить класс требуемой активити и в ней нужное вписать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не совсем понятно что конкретно нужно сделать.

Comment: Ну, вы мало информации в вопросе дали. Я слышал о инвайтах но ни разу не видел и не в курсе реализации. Я лишь предполагаю, что вы берёте некую либу и её используете. Также я предполагаю, что вы можете расширить класс активити инвайте, переопределить там onCreate метод и добавить нужное в тулбар. Если он там есть. Слишком мало инфы чтобы что-то конретное вам сказать

Comment: Вы приводите в вопросе фрагмент манифеста для DeepLinkActivity, а скриншот показываете для активити по отправке приглашения. Где стрелка должна быть?

Comment: @tse где вы увидели фрагмент в манифесте? стрелка должна отображаться левее иконки(account).

Comment: Не фрагмент в манифесте, а фрагмент (часть, кусок) манифеста, в котором описан DeepLinkActivity. Это ее скриншот?

Comment: @tse да+ добавил код самого layout'a